# Create a HotTowel site with login (facebook, twitter, google, microsoft)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hottowel

I am creating the site using the following steps.

1. Create a Asp.net Mvc 4 web application with standard "Internet
   application" template. So the login code is created. Then update all
   referenced code use NuGet.
2. Run `Install-Package HotTowel` and update all code using NeGet.

When I run the code.

1. It will go direct to the HotTowel `HotTowel\index.cshtml` instead of the page Home\Index.cshtml which has login code.
2. The generated html code of `HotTowel\index.cshtml` is wrapped in the generated html code of `Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

What I want is

The site shows the login page first, and redirect to the HotTowel home page after logged in.

## Update:

I tried to Install HotTowel on a pre-created built-in SPA project and got the similar issues.

## Update 2:

I found that commenting out the following lines in the file `HotTowelRouteConfig.cs` will make sure the start page go to `Home\Index.cshtml`.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
  typeof(test4.App_Start.HotTowelRouteConfig), "RegisterHotTowelPreStart", Order = 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

in your global.asax you need to add new route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and  your login ends on `return Redirect("/");` or `return RedirectToAction("HotTowel","index");`

Answer (score 0):

habe a look at [DurandalAuth](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth)   here is the live [Demo](https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/)  you can clone it with [mac.github](http://mac.github.com/)   or [windows.github](http://windows.github.com/)   and review the code i hope this will help you